# Is Sun's XML Instance Generator (xmlgen.jar) still available? If so, where?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Since Oracle took over Sun... this specific resource has apparently vanished.  I tried the Wayback Machine but that didn't work out.  Is there still a copy/archive of the Sun XML Instant Generator tool out there on the 'net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's good I never delete any of my bookmarks!

It is and it was a part of Sun Multi-Schema XML Validator (now - Oracle...). It's still available, but it's a *nightly* build from March 2006. I was not able to find anything newer than that. The source code is available as well in [SVN](http://java.net/projects/msv/sources/svn/show/trunk), confirming that it is an old tool.

It can be downloaded from [java.net](http://java.net/downloads/msv/nightly/xmlgen.20060319.zip).

Current sources, thanks to Kohsuke, are available on [github](https://github.com/kohsuke/msv/tree/master/generator). Easy to build, it's just Maven project.

Comment: The current version of msv is on github.

Comment: Since there tends to be random account closures at github, I forked a copy, too. https://github.com/starlocke/msv

Comment: Java.net is dead and I couldn't find a built jar elsewhere.